# Enabling C++ full optimization in xCode and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, optimization, compiler-optimization

in the other thread I asked about differences in time conduming by code calculations for Windows and for Mac.
Somebody told me that first I should be sure that on both machines code should be compiled with full optimization enabled.

Could anyone explain how to enable it? And check if it's already enabled or not?

Comment: Your IDE/toolchain's documentation explains how to do this, does it not?

Comment: Not sure, I’ll try to check, but as a beginner I suppose it will take me a lot of time, even not sure what exactly to looking for. But thanks for your exhaustive answer :)

Comment: Just enter "optimisation" into the search parameters for your documentation..

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try for sure

Comment: May be, this helps a bit: I just created a new project in VS2013 (to ensure default settings). Right click on project folder and Open Properties. Set Configuration (of property window) to Release. Choose (in the left tree of property window) C/C++/All Options. At the right side, I found Optimization. In my case, the default was `Optimize for speed (/O2)` which seemed reasonable to me for your case. OK (or Cancel as I didn't change anything). Now, chose Release (as target configuration) in the upper toolbar, compile, and Run (without debugging) (Ctrl+F5).

Comment: I've to admit that I wrote the above description by testing it in a German version of VS2013. Hence, my translations may not be 100 % accurate. Other versions of VS may look slightly different - I don't know.

Comment: Hey Scheff, thanks it’s great, it helped a lot. But now I am affraid it’s even little bit faster than my xCode compilation on Mac. So now I need to check if there is in the XCode some simillar settings to change.